# Paste image from the clipboard into a PDF in Preview

Tags: preview, copy-paste

The question title describes what should be a common/simple operation?  But I can not find the options to do it : After having copied an image to the clipboard -even from `Preview` itself - when right-clicking _nothing happens- ie. *no* context menu. And in `Edit`  we only see these options:

[image]

Is it the case that one can not  paste images atop an existing `Preview` window? What are simple alternatives?

Comment: Preview doesnt edit PDFs.  You need a program like Acrobat (not Acrobat Reader).

Comment: @Allan thanks  - Preview does allow adding annotations including text and polygons. I'm surprised that adding images is apparently significantly dfifferent/more difficult and not supported.  Feel free to create an answer

Comment: @Allan that isn't really a true statement since you can add text, boxes, circles, pen writing, arrows, etc to an existing PDF document and then save it.

Comment: @PaulWieland - you're arguing semantics.  You can annotate, but you can't *edit* it.  And by editing Apple/Adobe mean, *go in and change things as if it's part of the original document.*  Annotating is not editing from the functional side of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open a new file with that image in it. Copy your image to the clipboard and go to the File menu.  Under that, you'll see the option "Open from clipboard". This opens a new pdf with that image in it. You can then edit the image and include text by going to Tools/Annotate. You can't add this image to an existing pdf but you can merge 2 or more pdf by using the free app [PDFSam](https://pdfsam.org), which stands for PDF split and merge. So if I had a large PDF and i wanted to add an image i'd split the large PDF at the location I wanted to add the image. Then I'd merge the 3 in the correct order.

Comment: It's very easy to merge a few PDF pages with Preview:
- Open the two documents in separate Preview windows
- Show the thumbnails sidebar
- Drag pages from one sidebar to the other.

Answer (score 59):

You CAN do it. At least this is what worked for me on MacOS Catalina and Preview Version 11.

1. Copy onto the Clipboard, the image that you want to paste on your PDF page.
2. Go to Preview -> File -> New from Clipboard.
3. This will basically create a new Preview document with your image in it. Now click anywhere on the image, press Cmd+A to select the entire image, press Cmd+C to copy and then (this is the crucial part!!) press Delete to delete the image.
4. You will see a blank screen in Preview since you have deleted the image. Press Cmd+V and your image will reappear, but now, in a different format that can be copy-pasted across Preview documents.
5. Finally, select this 'new format' image using Cmd+A, copy it using Cmd+C and navigate to your PDF document and paste using Cmd+V.
6. In some cases if the document you are trying to paste into is still not allowing the paste, then repeat above but start with the other document (the document you are trying to paste into), do Cmd-A (select all) in that document, copy it (Cmd-C), paste it into a new document (File => New from clipboard), and now try again to paste your other document into this new one.

Voila! You can paste the image anywhere in your PDF document and on any page and you can resize and edit it just like you can with shapes. I think Apple didn't intend this to happen and I hope they don't read this and change this feature :P

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Mojave. Which OS version have you tested this in?

Comment: @benwiggy I'm on Catalina. The latest build of it. And Preview Version 11.0 (999.4)

Comment: @javadba My bad. Done.

Comment: It looks like a plausible and useful approach. With that first statement removed I have now been  able to upvote it.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Big Sur either.

Comment: @benwiggy Very strange. I just tried doing it with existing images on my laptop as well as by taking screenshots. It works for both. Don't know what's happening here.

Comment: And you're definitely pasting onto a PDF, not an image? I've tried png and jpg. Incidentally, when paste back the image into the deleted image window, the image has moved up by about 5mm, cropping off the top. (Preview is very buggy, and is not the best tool for.... anything.)

Comment: @benwiggy Yes, I'm pasting on to specific pages of a PDF document which has over 200 text pages. Also, I would suggest that you try doing this with screenshots. Press Cmd+Shift+5 to open all screenshot options and go to Options>Save to> Clipboard. Then using either Cmd+Shift+3 or Cmd+Shift+4, take a screenshot and create a New from Clipboard file in Preview. And then try all the steps with this screenshot. Would also suggest you check the version of Preview you are using. Mine is Version 11.0 (999.4)

Comment: Preview only comes with the OS, so the version is whatever it is. I've tried screenshots. It would be good to get some data from other users on this.

Comment: "This one weird trick..." I don't understand why, but this solution actually works (tested on Preview 11.0).

Comment: Works!! Big Sur M1. The last Copy paste didn't work first time, but then I clicked on the image and re-copy pasted and did work. So much time searching for pdf readers alternatives and it was right inside Preview... Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks a lot @ShikhinMehrotra. You have made my life a lot simpler :)

Comment: amazing! this works perfectly (m1, big sur)

Comment: Can't get it to work. Tried with screenshots and png files. Trying to past a signature into a PDF doc.

Comment: No freaking way. I had to do a cut, paste, and then a copy, but it works on macOS Monterey!

Comment: New from Clipboard can be done using Cmd + N.

Also, instead of Copying and Deleting, you can Cut with Cmd + X.

Comment: Wow, what a crazy trick, thank you!

Comment: @benwiggy I had difficulty too using this trick. I got around it by, after copying the image, deleting it and then reinserting it into Preview. This made sure I wasn't simply recopying the previous image instead of the newly pasted object.

Comment: That's amazing! Worked for me in Preview 11.0 using Monterey 12.6.9.

Answer (score 5):

Based on @Allan's comment that `Preview` does not support PDF's.  `Preview` *does* support some basic image editing facilities: so I am making `image` copies of the pdf pages and then super-imposing the other images on top of those images. This is working for my present needs.

Comment: +1 for "thinking out of the box" answer.  I added an answer with links to different options for editors - some paid and some free.

Comment: i went ahead and upvoted your answer: but yea i got through my current needs this way.

Answer (score 5):

Adding additional method to [Shikhin's](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/391135/shikhin-mehrotra) [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/405187/440227):

The exact sequence specified didn't work for me, however this did work for me:

Steps 1-4: As is.

Step 5: Instead of using ⌘-A, I used the "Grabber" hand to select the re-pasted image.

Step 6: I then hit ⌘-C.

Step 6: I was then able to ⌘-V into the PDF

Comment: This. Its freakin weird but this worked for me (13.2.1)

Comment: I think all that is needed is to select the image (⌘-A), copy the image (⌘-C), and then paste the image in the same window (⌘-V). After that first paste, I think the image is converted into an object, which can be pasted into other documents. Then repeat a similar process... click on the object, copy the object (⌘-C), and then paste the object into another document (⌘-V).

Answer (score 2):

**You need a PDF Creator/Editor.**

Preview does have some annotation capabilities, but you cannot edit. It's like drawing or writing on a pre-published form - you can mark it up, but you cant change it.

There are several PDF creators/editors available on the market.  In no particular order...

- [Adobe Acrobat](https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/acrobat.html) ($12.99/month)
- [PDFPenPro](https://smilesoftware.com/pdfpen/) ($75 USD)
- [Formulate Pro](https://code.google.com/archive/p/formulatepro/) (Free)
- [Libre Office Draw](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/draw/) (Free)
- [PFDescape](https://www.pdfescape.com/) (Free and Online only)

Personally, I used Adobe Acrobat X for my complex PDF creation and editing needs (when "Save As PDF" just wasn't enough).  This was before Adobe went Create Cloud and it means I'll be sticking with Mojave for as long as possible.

I've used other PDF creators in different environments and most "got the job done" but I always went back to Adobe.

Answer (score 2):

One way to place an image onto a PDF page (using bundled MacOS tools only) is to use Automator's Watermark PDF Documents action. You add the image file as the 'watermark', and then set the opacity, angle, size, position, etc.

Comment: Where can one find that automator action?

Comment: In Automator. It's called "Watermark PDF Documents".

Answer (score 2):

Preview allows you to add the image to the PDF as a new page via drag and drop:

1. Open the target PDF in Preview.
2. Open the image in a new Preview window via **File** > **New from Clipboard**.
3. In both windows, click **View** > **Contact Sheet**.
4. Drag the image thumbnail from one window into the PDF thumbnails in the other window; the image will be added to the PDF as a new page.

This method also works if you want to add pages from one PDF into another.